# Barplot does not evaluate data in R

Tags: r

Thanks in advance for your response.
I am trying to create a stacked bar plot from a csv file, and I have run into the following hiccup:
First I put the csv into a variable:

```
test <- read.csv(file=\"test4.csv\",sep=\",\",head=TRUE")
```

Then I try to create a bar plot using the following

```
barplot(test)
```

and I get the following error,

```
Error in barplot.default(test) : 'height' must be a vector or a matrix
```

so I try

```
barplot(t(test))
```

and it works but as expected the axis are switched, so I try

```
barplot(t(t(test)))
```

and it works, but I feel there must be a better solution than transposing the transposed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue is that [`read.csv` outputs a data frame](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/utils/html/read.table.html) and [`barplot` expects either a vector or a matrix](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/barplot.html).  The `barplot` function works when you transpose because [`t()` coerces data frames to matrices](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/t.html).

If you either start with

```
test <- as.matrix(read.csv(file="test4.csv",sep=",",head=TRUE))
```

or later on do

```
barplot(as.matrix(test))
```

then you should be fine.

Comment: Great!! side question: how can i state that the first column is not part of the data

Comment: You mean you don't want to include the first column of `test`?  In that case, you can call `barplot(as.matrix(test[,2:ncol(test)]))` (ie taking the columns of `test` starting with the second and ending with however many columns `test` has (which is `ncol(test)`)).