# How apply functions to csv files

Tags: r

```
limbs <- c(4, 3)
names(limbs) <- c('One-Eye', 'Peg-Leg')
```

To apply a barplot to above I use :

```
barplot(limbs)
```

How can I apply the same functionality to a .csv file ?
Is there a command I can use to set the limbs & names(limbs)
to the limbs,names columns ?

I've read the csv file into memory using : result <- read.csv(result.csv")

The format of the csv is :

```
names      limbs
'One-Eye' , 4
'Peg-Leg' , 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use the same approach that you use with a normal vector?

```
> limbs <- result$limbs
> names(limbs) <- result$names
> barplot(limbs)
```

Or, more directly:

```
> barplot(result$limbs, names.arg = result$names)
```

Comment: When I try youor code I receive this error : Error in names(limbs) <- result$names: 
  could not find function "names<-"      Do I need to import a package ?

Comment: Shouldn't need to. Try clearing your workspace and re-loading your csv as you mentioned you did in your answer. For clarification, the first line of your csv should have a comma between "names" and "limbs". Does it? If not, then your column names might not be "names" and "limbs" as they were when I read the file in.

Comment: You probably have a collision between the function `names` and the label `names` in your data object (or some other object in your workspace).

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, I liked "crash" better ;)

Comment: Me too, but "collision" is the more-or-less accepted word in software-ese.  :-)

Comment: @Ananda Mahto I needed to convert the results to a vector as this is what barplot expects : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8793831/barplot-does-not-evaluate-data-in-r